# Compare array items (items are arrays) if items in same position are equals

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, comparison, extendscript

**I'm using Adobe ExtendScript Toolkit to debug. I'm coding for InDesign and really don't have deep JavaScript knowledge (and don't know what ES6 means).
ExtendScript doesn't accept let as reserved word. Maybe something about this ES6 you're meaning?**

I need to compare all the items in an array and join some of them if one of its child are the same. Let me explain:

Based on the following array:

```
var array = [[1,"luis"] , [2,"felipe"] , [2,"erick"] , [2,"mark"] , [3,"dustin"]]
```

So, I want to get as result this array:

```
var array = [[1,"luis"] , [2,"felipe; erick; mark"] , [3,"dustin"]]
```

How can I compare the array items to get the desired result?

I already tried two for loops and a while.
Maybe I made them wrong. Because of that, I'm here to ask you guys.

If I use this:

```
for (var i=0; i<array.length-1; i++) {
    for (var j=i+1; j<array.length; j++) {
        if (array[i][0] == array[j][0]) {
            array[i][1] = array[i][1] + "; " + array[j][1];
            }
        }
    }
```

I have all results. Like this:

```
1,luis
2,felipe; erick; mark
2,erick; mark
2,mark
3,dustin
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.entries` and `reduce`.

```js
var array = [[1,"luis"] , [2,"felipe"] , [2,"erick"] , [2,"mark"] , [3,"dustin"]];
const res = Object.entries(array.reduce((a, [n, s]) => (a[n] = a[n] ? a[n] + "; " + s : s, a), {}));
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce`

```js
var array = [
  [1, "luis"],
  [2, "felipe"],
  [2, "erick"],
  [2, "mark"],
  [3, "dustin"]
]
const result = array.reduce(function(re, arr) {
  const item = re.find(function(o) {
    return o[0] === arr[0]
  })
  typeof item === 'undefined' ? re.push(arr) : (item[1] = item[1] + ';' + arr[1])
  return re
}, [])
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I'm using this code in Adobe ExtendScript Toolkit. Your snippet doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entries()` and Array's `.reduce()` methods to get the desired output:

```js
const data = [[1,"luis"] , [2,"felipe"] , [2,"erick"] , [2,"mark"] , [3,"dustin"]];

const result = Object.entries(data.reduce((r, [key, val]) => {
  r[key] = key in r ? [r[key].toString() + "; " + val] : val;
  return r;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I'm using this code in Adobe ExtendScript Toolkit. Your snippet doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce and map

- First group by first element in subarray
- map entries to desired format

```js
var array = [[1,"luis"] , [2,"felipe"] , [2,"erick"] , [2,"mark"] , [3,"dustin"]]

let op = array.reduce((op,inp)=>{
  op[inp[0]] = op[inp[0]] || []
  op[inp[0]].push(inp[1])
  return op
},{})

let final = Object.entries(op).map(([key,value])=> [+key,value.join('; ')])

console.log(final)
```

Comment: I'm using this code in Adobe ExtendScript Toolkit. Your snippet doesn't work for me.

Comment: @LuisFelipeCorullón it this toolkit doesn't support `ES6` and beyond then you can use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl) to transpile this code to `ES5`

Comment: ESTK is saying I need a ```;``` after op

Comment: Babel code doesn't work too. Now, ESTK says me array.reduce is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution below

```js
var array = [[1,"luis"] , [2,"felipe"] , [2,"erick"] , [2,"mark"] , [3,"dustin"]]

function mergeArrayBySameId(){
  let old = [];
  let mergedArr = [];
  array.map(function(curr, i){
    let tmp = "";
    let current = array[i];
    let prev    = ( i === 0 ) ? [] : array[i-1];

    if( current[0] === prev[0] ){
       tmp    = current[0];
       mergedArr[0] = tmp;

       if( !mergedArr.includes( prev[1] ) ){
          mergedArr.push( prev[1] );
       }

       mergedArr.push( current[1] );

    }
    old = prev;

  });

  let mergedStr = ""
  let mergedArrId = mergedArr[0];
  mergedArr.map(function(val){
     if( typeof val !== 'number' ){
          mergedStr += val + "; ";
     }
  });
  mergedArr = [];
  mergedArr[0] = mergedArrId;
  mergedArr[1] = mergedStr;

  function checkId(id){
    return mergedArr[0] != id[0];
  }

  let filterArray = array.filter(checkId);
  let finalArray = filterArray.concat([mergedArr]).sort();
  
  return finalArray;
}

console.log( mergeArrayBySameId() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your suggestions.
I'm sorry because I'm very beginner and just have familiarity with javascript while coding for Adobe software automation.
I found a way using:

```
var array = [[1,"luis"] , [2,"felipe"] , [2,"erick"] , [2,"mark"] , [3,"dustin"]];
for (var i=0; i<array.length-1; i++) {
    var j = i+1;
    while (j < array.length) {
        if (array[i][0] == array[j][0]) {
            array[i][1] = array[i][1] + "; " + array[j][1];
            array.splice(j , 1);
            j = i;
            }
        j++;
        }
    }
alert(array.join("\r"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [
    [1, "luis"],
    [3, "felipe"],
    [2, "erick"],
    [3, "mark"],
    [3, "dustin"]
];

let res = arr.reduce((acc,cur) => {
    const item = acc.find((obj) => {
        if(obj[0] === cur[0]){
            obj.push(cur[1]);
            return obj
        }
    });
    if(!item)
        acc.push(cur);
    return acc
},[]);
```